# Getting substring using ksh script

Tags: awk, ksh, substr

I'm using `ksh` script to determine what the delimiter in a file is using `awk`. I know this delimiter will always be in the 4 position on the first line. The issue I'm having is that the character being used as in a delimiter in a particular file is a `*` and so instead of returning `*` in the variable the script is returning a file list. Here is sample text in my file along with my script:

text in file:

```
XXX*XX*     *XX*XXXXXXX.......
```

here is my kind of what my script looks like (I don't have the script in front of me but you get the jist):

```
delimiter=$(awk '{substr $0, 4, 1}' file.txt)
echo ${delimiter} # lists files in directory..file.txt file1.txt file2.txt instead of * which is the desired result
```

Thank you in advance,
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is interpreting the content of the `delimiter` variable. You need to quote it to avoid this behaviour:

```
echo "${delimiter}"
```

It will print `*`

Comment: I just figured that out this morning and was going to edit my posting....thanks for you response!

Answer (score 1):

Birei is right about your problem. But your AWK expression doesn't seem to be interested in the 1st line only. You can replace it with :

```
'NR==1 {print substr($0, 4, 1)}'
```

Then you can do a simple:

```
echo "$delimiter"
```